# Поменять в GoogleChallengeProperties redirect url c http на https

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth, google-account

Недавно гугл стал требовать, чтобы при логине через него все redirect url были в виде https

Вот мой метод аутентификации, ранее работал

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleLogin(string returnUrl)
        {
            var redirectUrl = Url.Action("GoogleLoginCallback", "Account", new { ret = returnUrl });

            AuthenticationProperties prop = new GoogleChallengeProperties();
            prop.RedirectUri = redirectUrl;
            return new ChallengeResult("Google", prop);

        }
```

А теперь выдает ошибку

Ошибка 400: invalid_request

Невозможно выполнить вход в приложение, поскольку оно не отвечает правилам Google в отношении безопасности OAuth 2.0.

Если вы разработчик приложения, убедитесь, что эти параметры запроса соответствуют правилам Google.
redirect_uri: http://mysite/signin-google

Ну и в консоли гугла соответственно при попытке вставить допустимый для редиректа адрес с http

```
Invalid Redirect: This app has a publishing status of "In production". URI must use https:// as the scheme.
```

Как отсылать гуглу https адрес? То что я шлю в ChallengeResult - содержит относительный адрес, типа /account/signin-google, там нет места под https. Где указать что мой редирект url начинается именно с https?

Comment: а у вас приложение хостится с использованием https (есть валидные сертификаты и заходите по https)?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten
Да

Единственное, там внутри есть nginx и внешне он все делает по https, а внутри вполне может быть и по http. Но снаружи туда никак не постучатся. 


Возможно надо что-то добавить сюда

`AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = "myclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                    options.ClientSecret = "mysecret";
                });`
А то тут только айди и секрет. Может тут как то в параметрах указывается, что return url должен быть https

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас приложение стоит за `nginx` (выполняющего роль прокси), а внутри оно использует обычный `http` (т.е. происходит `ssl termination`), то при проксировании трафика вам нужно дополнительно пробрасывать заголовки, например:

```
proxy_set_header   Host               $host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

А в `asp.net core` приложении добавить их поддержку:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All,
    KnownNetworks =
    {
        new IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.0.0"), 16)
    }
});
```

В `KnownNetworks` нужно указывать из "доверенной" сети из которой будут приниматься эти заголовки (в приведенном примере указана дефолтная приватная подсеть докера, например, если у вас `nginx` и приложение запущены как разные контейнеры), без этого `asp.net core` будет просто их игноритовать и разрешать только из `localhost` (например, когда `nginx` и приложение запущены на одной машине).

После этого в `Challenge` должен генерироваться правильный `redirect_uri`.